# How do I add a library to my project while keeping them in the same directory/not have the library be a system library?

Tags: c++, include, libraries

So I am pretty new to programming and decided to improve by making a simple game. For this I need multiple libraries (SDL for example). I understand that libraries should be compiled from their source, which I do with mingw64 and cmake. Cmake creates some files and a makefile, which I run with mingw to get a .DLL and .DLL.a file.
As I want to make a game that can be downloaded in one clean package, I want all the necessary libraries to be in the same directory as my game.
I think I've figured out how to link to the .DLL and .DLL.a with the command line, but the problem are the headers.
I am on windows coding in c++ with vscodium.

SDL has a ton of headers, but even if I copy all of them to my game's directory and include the main header in my code I get an error from the main header saying it does not know the other headers it in turn includes (the myriad other SDL headers).
I guess the problem might be that the main header uses <> instead of "" to include, however it feels like going through that massive file and editing every instance of this isn't the intended way.

Comment: ***I understand that libraries should be compiled from their source, which I do with mingw64 and cmake.*** For MinGW I recommend you use msys2 to install MinGW and use the built in package management `pacman` to install all of the dependent libraries. No need to build them from source or put any third party libraries or their headers in the same folders as your project. Leave them where they are in the system location of your compiler you installed via msys2.

Comment: Yes, but should I want to ship my game I need to include the libraries I use as part of the package my player downloads, no? If so the libraries installed via msys2 would not work, as they are installed on my pc but not on my player's?

Comment: ***Yes, but should I want to ship my game I need to include the libraries I use as part of the package my player downloads, no*** It depends on the level of your users. You may end up shipping binaries that are incompatible with the compiler your users are using.  These days many projects will use CMake and let the user use their compiler of choice and instead list the dependencies which they can install on their own. Or have CMake download and compile the source for them as part of the build using https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html

Comment: ***I guess the problem might be that the main header uses <> instead of "" to include, however it feels like going through that massive file and editing every instance of this isn't the intended way.*** I believe the replacement will not be necessary. Most compilers I know of will search the same folder as the source file after the system headers and headers included on the compiler's command line.

Comment: You don't need to ship the headers with your game, they're only used by the compiler

Comment: Ok, so I solved it. I just had to put the headers in the mingw include folder that I found by running gcc -v.